# Can I use a VM for MOSS (SharePoint) 2007 production environment?

Tags: virtual-machine, moss, production

I am currently working on a fairly simple company intranet based on MOSS 2007 with around 1400 users, a few blogs and wikis, minimal file sharing and no My Sites (at the moment).

We are considering deploying to a VM for the production environment but I have not been able to find much information on doing this. We mostly use VMWare, though I guess it would be possible to use the MS Virtual PC if necessary. If I remember correctly, only Virtual PC is officially supported, right?

- What experience have you had of such a deployment?
- Any problems using VMWare?
- How should the server be dimensioned?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com. You'll get better answers there too.

Comment: @Alex: I would have thought so too, but there seems to be very little sharepoint discussion there so I posted where the masses are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a similar question on MSDN and got a number of useful answers:

[MSDN Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/c441c557-b604-44bf-9335-fa17fcca2c9d)

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem with VMWare, not sure about support though.

The server sizing needs to be proporonate to site's concurrent usage. If 100 users are hitting the website at same time, its adviseable to host this site seperately.

Ideally, 2GB of RAM with 100 GB of webspace should be enuf.